# Loading JSON data in mongodb using sparksql

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON file and i want to load the same into MongoDB using Spark SQL. I had the way of loading individual elements into a collection like below

```
val mongoClient = MongoClient(127.0.0.1, 27017)
val collection = mongoClient(dbname)(collection_name)
for (a <- 1 to 10) {
  collection.insert {
    MongoDBObject("id" -> a.toString,
      "age" -> (10 + a),
      "description" -> s"description $a",
      "enrolled" -> (a % 2 == 0),
      "name" -> s"Name $a")
  }
```

Since MongoDB already stores the data in JSON format, is there any way to load my JSON file directly ?

Comment: No, MongoDB doesn't store data in JSON format. It is using BSON which is not the same thing. You could dump to JSON and read from there but it is far from directly. Also it won't be able to push-down predicates like for example Stratio.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the bottom data format for MongoDB is **BSON**, but remember we can use `mongoexport` to export MongoDB document in json format. Maybe it's irrelevant to your case, my point is we can actually load json file with [SparkSQL](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html), following is how I try to get it done.

One important library we need here is [Spark library for easy MongoDB access](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB).

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import com.stratio.datasource.mongodb._
import com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.MongodbConfig._

object DFToMongoDB extends App {

  lazy val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("mongodb")
    .setMaster("local[4]"))

  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

  /*
    sample data in xxx.json  

    {
      "_id":"xxxx","workHome":false,"commute":true,
      "tel":false,"weekend":true,"age":100.0
    }
  */
  val dataFrame = sqlContext.read.json("xxx.json")

  def forCollection(collectionName: String) = {
    MongodbConfigBuilder(
      Map(
        Host -> List("127.0.0.1"), Database -> "xxx", 
        Collection -> collectionName,
        SamplingRatio -> 1.0, 
        WriteConcern -> com.mongodb.casbah.WriteConcern.Acknowledged,
        SplitSize -> 8, SplitKey -> "_id"
      )
    ).build
  }

  // dataFrame will be converted to MongodbDataFrame here 
  dataFrame.saveToMongodb(forCollection("xxx"))
}
```

Besides, the case I try is **the collection does not exist in MongoDB before the load**, after that MongoDB will create the collection with records in the json file. As for the other cases, you can try if you like.

Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: Alan, When i try the above function, its showing me an error. Its saying the options inside MongodbConfigBuilder are not available. I'm using Spark 1.4 version and spark-mongodb_2.10-0.9.2.jar.  Can you able to help ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have told you the verison. I am using spark-core 1.5.1 and spark-mongodb 0.10.3. Maybe it's a problem caused by verison. Try to upgrade the version if you can. Or look up the ```com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.MongodbConfigBuilder``` in your verison and try to import the options explicitly instead of using the wildcard.